# Do "Magic Bars" exist outside of Japan?

Tags: japan, entertainment

Do "Magic Bars" (マジックバー) (is there a more common term for it in English?), bars at which magic is performed, exist outside of Japan?

Examples:

- [EM Power Magic](http://www.empowermagic.jp/)
- [Another example](http://r.gnavi.co.jp/e533322/)
- [Magic Bar 10 o'clock](https://www.facebook.com/10ji.japan?hc_location=ufi)

Comment: Magic as in card tricks and so?

Comment: Can we have some examples?

Comment: @NeanDerThal that's right. Just entertainment, no interactions with jinns or witchcraft like [Fawza Falih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fawza_Falih).

Comment: Just look for Magic Show

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: @Flimzy It's somewhat about travel but it is too broad.

Comment: If it was about where to find a Magic Bar in XYZ place, I would consider it about travel. As it's worded, it seems to be just about cultural uniqueness of Japan.

Comment: What? "All countries other than Japan" not specific enough? :) Fair enough that it got closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know (but I've never been to any of them) a few places like [this one](http://www.restauranteanthonysplace.com/cenas-con-espectaculo) in Madrid but they are not very popular. They usually offer the option of having dinner in front of the magicians while they perform tricks, sometimes involving the audience in some degree or another.

The description of the show is a bit vague:

> El espectáculo consistirá en Magia de cerca por las mesas + 1 hora de Magia & Humor donde los comensales más animados podrán colaborar con nuestros magos en la elaboración de sus trucos.

Which translates roughly (if someone feels like he/she could improve the translation feel free to do it) as:

> The show will have two parts: one hour of magic around the tables + one hour of "Magic+Humor" when the most extroverts customers will be able to help our magicians when performing their tricks.

I expect that the situation is similar in other major cities.

I don't know if this is what you were looking for exactly.